# Center items in RecyclerView grid

Tags: android, android-layout

I have main layout which includes my View which have RecyclerView and have grid applied on it. Now items have default width because of drawable i apply, and now they are aligned to left instead to center what i want to achieve.

My main layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include android:id="@+id/constraint_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/list_more_view"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

More layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_more_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_more_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text_color"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_closemore"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/close_button"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textview_title_more"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_morelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_title_more" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintlayout_item_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/plate_basic">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_unit_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:textColor="@color/item_text_color"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tile_title_padding"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So the thing is items in this more view are all aligned to left but i want the whole view of items centred, i tried with setting the width to wrap content and than centring with gravity but no success.

Comment: is there a reason for using 150dp as width in your item layout?

Answer (score 0):

Change **constraintlayout_item_view** to have:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Then set **textview_unit_title** to have:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

That should place the TextView centered inside its row.

In addition, your main layout's width and height are a little strange:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

They should probably both be `match_parent`

Comment: That works fine for gird, but as i said i use this item in other recycler view where is horizontal scroll and there are few items displayed, if i use match parent than only 1 item per swipe will be visible in horizontal recycler

Comment: Nope, you never said.